# Printing Array elements using GetIntArrayElements in JNI

Tags: java, android, c, java-native-interface

I want to use `GetIntArrayElements` to print contents of an `jint` array.
My code is as follows.

**JNI Code (C):**

```
#define LOGI(...) __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "JNI", __VA_ARGS__)

int size = 5;
jint test_arr[size] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};      /* Array to be printed */

jintArray result_arr = (*env)->NewIntArray(env, size);
(*env)->SetIntArrayRegion(env, result_arr, 0, size, test_arr);

/* Print the Value of the Array */
jint *ptr = (*env)->GetIntArrayElements(env, result_arr, NULL);

for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    LOGI("[%d]", *(ptr + i));

(*env)->ReleaseIntArrayElements(env, result_arr, ptr, NULL);
```

**Output:**

```
I/[JNI] ( 1835): [0]
I/[JNI] ( 1835): [1092010456]
I/[JNI] ( 1835): [1092201680]
I/[JNI] ( 1835): [1526497088]
I/[JNI] ( 1835): [0]
```

**Expected Output:**

```
I/[JNI] ( 1835): [1]
I/[JNI] ( 1835): [2]
I/[JNI] ( 1835): [3]
I/[JNI] ( 1835): [4]
I/[JNI] ( 1835): [5]
```

My final objective is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24991970/passing-an-array-from-jni-to-java).
I believe the Array is not getting correctly passed to Java from JNI.

**Is this the correct way to print the array elements ?**
I'm fairly new to JNI. Require some help on the same.

Answer (score 0):

Your JNI is fine, you just messed up how you access the array.  You cannot assume jint will be 1 byte, in reality it's probably a long int that is 4 bytes... use the sizeof operator to let the compiler decide what it should be based on the system you are targeting ;)

change `LOGI("[%d]", *(ptr + i));` 
to `LOGI("[%ld]", *(ptr + (sizeof(jint) * i)));`

Updated: I didn't catch this before but it looks like you reversed result_arr and test_arr in `(*env)->SetIntArrayRegion(env, result_arr, 0, size, test_arr);`  You want to read from test_arr and write to result_arr `(*env)->SetIntArrayRegion(env, test_arr, 0, size, result_arr);`